# How to solve this exercise using for-loop?

Tags: java

How do you solve this using for loop? and which is more better, for loop or just `lastIndexOf`?

Here's the problem and three test cases:

Given two strings, return true if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive"). Note: str.toLowerCase() returns the lowercase version of a string.

endOther("Hiabc", "abc") → true

endOther("AbC", "HiaBc") → true

endOther("abc", "abXabc") → true

Here's my code:

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {

String newA = a.toLowerCase();
String newB = b.toLowerCase();

if(a.length() >= b.length() && newA.lastIndexOf(newB) == (a.length() - b.length() ) ) return true;
if(b.length() >= a.length() && newB.lastIndexOf(newA) == (b.length() - a.length() ) ) return true;

return false;
}
```

Comment: or [.endsWith](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_endswith.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Case you need a for loop you can go with the below code.

```
 public static boolean check(String s1,String s2)
{
    boolean result = false;

    if(s1.length() >= s2.length())
    {
        result = compare(s1, s2);
    }
    else
    {
        result = compare(s2,s1);
    }


    return  result;
}

public static boolean compare(String s1,String s2)
{
    boolean result = false;
    char[] array1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] array2 = s2.toCharArray();
    if(array1.length>=array2.length)
    {
        int j = array2.length-1;
        for(int i = array1.length-1;i>=0;i--,j--)
        {
            if(j==0)
            {
                if(!(array1[i]==array2[j]))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(!(array1[i]==array2[j]))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

But the better way is already provided by @upma.

Answer (score 1):

The code is like below, hope that it can help you. Check the native method of **java.lang.String** first before you want to do something about the String.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(endOther("Hiabc", "abc"));
        System.out.println(endOther("AbC", "HiaBc"));
        System.out.println(endOther("abc", "abXabc"));
    }

    public static boolean endOther(String a, String b){
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        if (a.length() >= b.length()) {
            return a.endsWith(b);
        }else {
            return b.endsWith(a);
        }
    }
}
```